# Facebook likebox developer with problems

Tags: facebook, account, facebook-likebox

In this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/, my account
don't return any data. How to fix it? I want embed in my site. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that some code (if possible [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) will help us to help you. (Please show what you have tried so far](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 0):

Enter facebook page  url  on given link page textbox, and set height and width.

Comment: i already made that. It doesn't work. With other page url worked. Might be settings/privacy of facebook account?